# How to display featured content first and then the rest in a scope?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an app with a lot of content. Right now I have a boolean called `featured`. When `feature` is marked, I'd like this content to display at the top of the page. Right now, I have a scope order on the content, but I'm not sure how to display the featured items first. Any thoughts?  Below are the small scopes I have for content:

```
  scope :published, where(:published => true )
  scope :unpublished, where(:published => false )
  scope :ordering, order("published_date desc")
  scope :feature, where(feature: true )
```

Here is what my home controller looks like that displays the content:

```
  def index
    @contents = Content.includes(:author).published.ordering
    @collections = @user.try(:collections)
    @categories = Category.includes(:subcategories).all
  end
```

It seems like there's a better way to do this than an if else statement. Suggestions? I've been looking at the order documentation and not finding anything specific for this case.

Using:
Rails 3.2.14
Ruby 1.9.3

Answer (score 1):

You can use a SQL CASE WHEN clause in the order to define a specific behavior on a specific attribute's value:

```
scope :ordered_by_featured_then_published, order("CASE contents.featured = 't' THEN 'a' ELSE 'b' END ASC, contents.published_date DESC")
# for readability, content of the order method:
# "CASE contents.featured = 't' THEN 'a' ELSE 'b' END ASC, contents.published_date DESC"
```

This SQL CASE WHEN works for me with PostGreSQL. You might have to make some syntax changes here, but you got the concept.

And use it that way:

```
@contents = Content.includes(:author).published.ordered_by_featured_then_published
```

---

Some explanations:

- "`content.featured = 't'`" => This will test if the value of `content.featured = TRUE` (in PostGreSQL, `TRUE`s are saved as 't', `FALSE`s as 'f')
- "`CASE contents.featured = 't' THEN 'a' ELSE 'b' END`" => if featured is TRUE, returns the letter 'a', if not, return 'b'
- "`ORDER BY CASE contents.featured = 't' THEN 'a' ELSE 'b' END ASC`": with the statement above, we order (ascendant) on a list of "a" and "b" => if featured is TRUE, returns "a" else returns "b", then order on the returned list of letters

Hope this helps!

Comment: @LMo you should accept an answer if it fits your question, and eventually vote up if the answer was better than expected!

Comment: Can you give a quick explanation of the t, a and b? I'm just not sure exactly what they are referring to. Also... I will do the vote up once I get it. Thanks again.

Comment: I see - so you take into account if there isn't featured content.

Answer (score 1):

```
scope :order_by_feature_then_published, order("contents.feature DESC").order("published_date DESC")


  def index
    @contents = Content.includes(:author).published.order_by_feature_then_published
    @collections = @user.try(:collections)
    @categories = Category.includes(:subcategories).all
  end
```

This works.

Comment: Does anyone know what kind of effect this might have on pagination?

Comment: No effect on the pagination, this is still an ActiveRecord::Relation object ;)

Comment: Will it throw an error if there isn't featured content if I don't use the if/else statement?

Comment: It won't raise an error if the list contains no record marqued as "featured", same if the list is completely empty.